# Issue with ExpressionEngine caching file permissions

Tags: caching, configuration, file-permissions, expressionengine

I am trying to allow caching for my site using expressionengine 2.0. In my config.php file, I have set the following two parameters:

```
$config['cache_driver'] = 'file';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
```

Initially there was no cache directory, so I created a cache directory with 755 permissions. However, on expressengine's admin page, when I try to set caching to File, it keeps on saying in a writing next to it in red:

[image]

Note that my cache directory doesn't have anything in it. Its at the correct path

www/mysite/system/expressionengine/cache

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

cache folders must need permission of 777. If your path is correct and config vars are correctly defined, you just need to give 777 permission to cache folder.